# Variable declared outside and value of variable modified in XMLHttpRequest is not visible outside this Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

The Variable declared outside:

```
var total=0;

on success of AJAX{

total++;
alert(total);// gives value
}

alert(total)// gives zero value
```

Here I am getting the total value to be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ajax` request is likely *asynchronous*. This means that your `alert` happens *before* the response has returned.

Any code that relies on the response *(like your alert)* needs to be placed in your `onreadystatechange` handler.

Comment: I am setting this value of total in document after the ajax call.

Comment: @Judy That won't make a difference if the call is asynchronous

Comment: @Judy: Right, and the ajax call is *asynchronous*. As in *not syncronous*. As in, it happens *out of order*. In other words, the request *does not block* subsequent code from executing before the response returns.

Comment: @Judy The order of written code is irrelevant to order of execution when dealing with function calls. The AJAX request is made, the alert happens, the AJAX calls the callback function.

Comment: On success of the code I am incrementing the value inside the ajax. If I do alert inside ajax I get some value but outside ajax (once its is executed) I get zero value

Comment: @Judy: Yes, I know. Again, the request is *asyncronous*. Any code you wrote that comes *after* the request, will execute *before* the response is complete. Did you happen to notice that you get the `0` alert before the `1` alert? One more time... any code that relies on the response needs to be place inside the callback. That's why there's a callback. If the request was synchronous, there would be no point in having a callback at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what is actually the question, but it sounds like the typical *asyncronous* confusion. A `XMLHttpRequest` by default, runs async and its *callbacks* fire when an event is encountered (like, readyState 4).

So, your `alert()` statement most likely is encountered before any of your ajax handlers does fire.

So, the easy solution is, move that `alert()` into your `.onreadystatechange` respectively `.onload` event handler, to the very bottom of the part that handles the `success`.

The worst solution (even if nobody would recommend that) is to setup your `XMLHttpRequest` as *syncronous*. That means, for the time that request is running, your browser and its UI thread are locked down, until the request finishes.